# What does StreamingContextStates.Clone actually do?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

The book `CLR Via C#` presents a simple way to clone objects via binary serialization.

It specifies `StreamingContextStates.Clone` when creating the `BinaryFormatter` like so:

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter
{
    Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone)
};
```

[The documentation for `StreamingContextStates.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontextstates.aspx) says that it

> Specifies that the object graph is being cloned. Users can assume that the cloned graph will continue to exist within the same process and be safe to access handles or other references to unmanaged resources.

Well fair enough - but I don't really know what this actually means. In what way does this actually change the behaviour of the `BinaryFormatter`? Can anyone list any concrete effects that using this flag has?

Comment: For the record, I **strongly** suggest that you avoid `BinaryFormatter` in, well, most circumstances. It has some things where it is handy, but I've seen *so many* people have *so much* pain caused from this... indeed, the issues in `BinaryFormatter` were part of why I got heavily involved in serialization a few years back

Comment: This property is re-exposed in `ISerializable.GetObjectData(...)`, so technically any implementation **could in theory** choose to do something different based on the `StreamingContextStates` value. I don't know how many, if any, *do*, though

Comment: @MarcGravell Interesting, thanks. (And perhaps that sample should be taken out of CLR Via C# for the next edition then. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Serialization is the subject here. 
MS provided an "abstract" mini-framework to allow serialization of objects.
Binary formatter is a specific implementation of that mini-framework concepts.

A developer may choose to use that framework concepts to create his own custom formatter  - or -
MS itself when creating the mini-framework thought of further implementation of serialization.

So they provided those flags as part of the framework.

To answer your specific question: those flags will not have any effect to binary formatter as it is already implemented as a tool (if you like) to track the object graph and simply convert it into bytes of raw data.
If you create your own serializer which in example can save the object to a database or to a file or to shared memory or whatever - you would want the user who using your serializer to specify the corresponding flag.

Unless I totally misunderstood MS devs since 2003 .. :) (which is possible!)